# regexp to extract an URL components

Tags: regex, url, uri

I am trying to write a regexp to extract an URL components. The syntax can be found here: [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#page-16).

Some of the components are optional. So far I have:

```
(.+)://((.*)@)?(.+?)(:(\d*))?/((.*)\?)?((.*)#)?(.*)
```

The decomposition is:

- `(.+)://` matches the scheme followed by `://`. Not optional.
- `((.*)@)?` matches the user information part of authority. Optional.
- `(.+?)` matches the host. Not optional. <s>There is an issue here where this group *will also match* the optional port.</s>
- `(:(\d*))?` <s>*should*</s> matches the port.
- `/` this and all that follows should be made optional.
- `((.*)\?)?` matches the path part. Optional.
- `((.*)#)?` matches the query part. Optional.
- `(.*)` matches the fragment part. Optional.

How can I improve this regexp so that it is RFC3986-valid ?

Fun fact: this regexp matches itself.

Example URL (taken from the RFC): `foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose`

**Edit:** I forgot to escape `d`. Now all that's left to do is to make everything that follows the *host* optional, including the leading `/`.

Comment: Please give an example of a URI you may be using

Comment: I just found I need to escape `d` to march numbers. It should be `\b`

Comment: As a side note, your pattern uses parts like `.*` and `.+` which use a dot that can match any character including spaces and will match till the end of the string first. This can possibly lead to unexpected matches. Is there a particular set of url's what you want to match / not match? Are they part of a larger text or the only url on a single line?

Comment: The only requirement is that if the regexp matches something, it must be a valid URL as per RFC-3986. It can produce undesirable results like: `hello world foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose some extra text here` produces a match. It's undesirable but it still is a valid URL as per the RFC (unless you can't have spaces in the scheme, which should be addressed I guess).

Comment: Also the fragment part can be any length, it could be a whole book for that matter ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression works fine if you just escape the slashes and preferably the colon as well. The result is `(.+)\:\/\/(.*@)?(.+?)(:(\d*))?\/((.*)\?)?((.*)#)?(.*)`. Here is a simple script to show how it can be used to filter out invalid URIs:

**Update**
Following the comments I have made the following modification:

- I have added `(\:((\d*)\/))?(\/)*`. Explanation:

  - `\:((\d*)` matches a colon and then any string of digits.
  - the `\/` after this matches a slash which should be after this string of digits. This is because the port must not contain any other characters but digits. So they cannot be found in the port-portion of the uri.
  - Finally, the entire port-matching expression is optional, hence the `?`.
  - The last part indicates that many or no slashes can follow the existing/non-existing port

**Final regExp:**
`(.+)\:\/\/(.*\@)?(.+?)(\:((\d*)\/))?(\/)*((.*)\?)?((.*)\#)?(.*)`

```js
const myRegEx = new RegExp("(.+)\:\/\/(.*\@)?(.+?)(\:((\d*)\/))?(\/)*((.*)\?)?((.*)\#)?(.*)", "g");

const allUris = [
  /*Valid*/ "https://me@data.www.example.com:5050/page?query=value#element", 
  /*Valid*/ "foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose",
  /*Valid*/ "foo://example.com",
  /*Not valid*/ "www.example.com"];


const allowedUris = allUris.map(uri => {
  // Use the regexp to match it, then return the match
  const match = uri.match(myRegEx);
  return match;
});

console.log("Here are the valid URIs:");
console.log(allowedUris.join("\n\n")); // Should only print the first two URIs from the array.
```

Comment: Thanks, there is just one issue left: `foo://example.com` should be matched because the trailing `/` (and everything that follows) is optional. I tried to wrap that in `()?` but it breaks the regexp.

Comment: Ok, check the updated answer

Comment: Actually the capture groups are broken :-( You can try print them with `scheme: $1, user: $2, host: $3, port: $6, path: $9, query: $11, fragment: $12`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better way to handle this, while also not breaking the capture groups.

```
(\w[\w\d\+\.-]*)://(.+@)?([^:/\?#]+)(:\d+)?(/[^\?#]*)?(\?[^#]+)?(#.*)?
```

Decomposition:

- `(\w[\w\d\+\.-]*)://` matches a valid scheme, as per RFC-3986.
- `(.+@)?` matches user information; i.e. everything until `@`, optionally.
- `([^:/\?#]+)` matches host; i.e. everything until `:` or `/` or `?` or `#` is encountered.
- `(:\d+)?` matches port; i.e. all digits, optionally
- `(/[^\?#]*)?` matches path; i.e. `/` plus optionally every character until `?` or `#` is encountered, optionally.
- `(\?[^#]+)?` matches query; i.e. `?` plus every characters until `#` is encountered, optionally.
- `(#.*)?` matches fragment; i.e. `#` plus everything after, optionally.

**EDIT:** final version I'm using (capture groups added for better extraction + discarding new-line characters):

```
(\w[\w\d\+\.-]*)://((.+)@)?([^:/\?#\r\n]+)(:(\d+))?(/([^\?#\r\n]*))?(\?([^#\r\n]*))?(#(.*))?
```

[Try it online](https://www.online-cpp.com/Ph5r1JgA7f) against randomly generated url's.